# Typescript: prevent use of ".name" to get function/class name

Tags: javascript, typescript

is there an easy way (maybe tslint rule) to prevent us from using MyClass.name, or myFunction.name?

We're trying to make sure no Dev end up using this, as the minification process will change method names.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I think you're missing a bit of the question. "We're trying to make sure any Dev end up using these", what does these refer to?

Comment: sorry, I didn't check what I wrote, I fixed it.

Comment: Yes, a [custom linting rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/docs/getting-started/plugin-development) should be able to do this

Answer (score 1):

Untested, so mileage may vary from 0 to 100, but you can try the following. Inside a global/ambient ts file write:

```
declare global {
  interface Function {
    /** @deprecated Don't use this, think about the children!*/
    readonly name: string;
  }
}
```

Then set in your tslint config:

```
"rules": {
  "deprecation": true
}
```

Perhaps this will warn the developer with a deprecation notice, but there is also a possibility it's ignored, because the lib typings do not have this comment

Comment: I kinda help, but it still let you build javascript... it's only a warning... I was thinking of something more intrusive... maybe I'll have to create a tslint rule myself?